# Validation in Zend Framework 2 with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am right now getting myself more and more familiar with Zend Framework 2 and in the meantime I was getting myself updated with the validation part in Zend Framework 2. I have seen few examples how to validate the data from the database using Zend Db adapter, for example the code from the Zend Framework 2 official website:

```php
//Check that the username is not present in the database
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists(
    array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'field' => 'username'
    )
);
if ($validator->isValid($username)) {
    // username appears to be valid
} else {
    // username is invalid; print the reason
    $messages = $validator->getMessages();
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
        echo "$message\n";
    }
}
```

Now my question is how can do the validation part?

For example, I need to validate a name before inserting into database to check that the same name does not exist in the database, I have updated Zend Framework 2 example Album module to use Doctrine 2 to communicate with the database and right now I want to add the validation part to my code.

Let us say that before adding the album name to the database I want to validate that the same album name does not exist in the database.

Any information regarding this would be really helpful!

Comment: Not too familiar with ZF2 yet, but here is a hint: Create your own validator taking the default one as example =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it this way:

1. Create a custom validator class, name it something like `NoEntityExists` (or whatever you want).
2. Extend `Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator`
3. Provide a getter and setter for `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`
4. Provide some extra getters and setters for options (entityname, ...)
5. Create an `isValid($value)` method that checks if a record exists and returns a boolean
6. To use it, create a new instance of it, assign the `EntityManager` and use it just like any other validator.

To get an idea of how to implement the validator class, check the validators that already exist (preferably a simple one like `Callback` or `GreaterThan`).

Hope I could help you.

// Edit: Sorry, I'm late ;-)

So here is a quite advanced example of how you can implement such a validator.

Note that I added a `translate()` method in order to catch language strings with PoEdit (a translation helper tool that fetches such strings from the source codes and puts them into a list for you). If you're not using `gettext()`, you can problably skip that.

Also, this was one of my first classes with ZF2, I wouldn't put this into the `Application` module again. Maybe, create a new module that fits better, for instance `MyDoctrineValidator` or so.

This validator gives you a lot of flexibility as you have to set the query before using it. Of course, you can pre-define a query and set the entity, search column etc. in the options. Have fun!

```
<?php
namespace Application\Validator\Doctrine;

use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class NoEntityExists extends AbstractValidator
{
    const ENTITY_FOUND = 'entityFound';

    protected $messageTemplates = array();

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    protected $query;

    /**
     * Determines if empty values (null, empty string) will <b>NOT</b> be included in the check.
     * Defaults to true
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $ignoreEmpty = true;

    /**
     * Dummy to catch messages with PoEdit...
     * @param string $msg
     * @return string
     */
    public function translate($msg)
    {
        return $msg;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $ignoreEmpty
     */
    public function getIgnoreEmpty()
    {
        return $this->ignoreEmpty;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $ignoreEmpty
     */
    public function setIgnoreEmpty($ignoreEmpty)
    {
        $this->ignoreEmpty = $ignoreEmpty;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param unknown_type $entityManager
     * @param unknown_type $query
     */
    public function __construct($entityManager = null, $query = null, $options = null)
    {
        if(null !== $entityManager)
            $this->setEntityManager($entityManager);
        if(null !== $query)
            $this->setQuery($query);

        // Init messages
        $this->messageTemplates[self::ENTITY_FOUND] = $this->translate('There is already an entity with this value.');

        return parent::__construct($options);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     * @return \Application\Validator\Doctrine\NoEntityExists
     */
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $query
     */
    public function getQuery()
    {
        return $this->query;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $query
     */
    public function setQuery($query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see \Zend\Validator\ValidatorInterface::isValid()
     * @throws Exception\RuntimeException() in case EntityManager or query is missing
     */
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        // Fetch entityManager
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        if(null === $em)
            throw new Exception\RuntimeException(__METHOD__ . ' There is no entityManager set.');

        // Fetch query
        $query = $this->getQuery();

        if(null === $query)
            throw new Exception\RuntimeException(__METHOD__ . ' There is no query set.');

        // Ignore empty values?
        if((null === $value || '' === $value) && $this->getIgnoreEmpty())
            return true;

        $queryObj = $em->createQuery($query)->setMaxResults(1);

        $entitiesFound = !! count($queryObj->execute(array(':value' => $value)));

        // Set Error message
        if($entitiesFound)
            $this->error(self::ENTITY_FOUND);

        // Valid if no records are found -> result count is 0
        return ! $entitiesFound;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your help, in case if you could provide some example code, would be much more helpful, just a skeleton of the code would do

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to. I'm at work and can't copy my code. I also don't have time to write something right now, but I can check on that this evening (that's in 3-4 hrs).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply again, I mean you dont need to replicate your exact code, thats what I meant just a skeleton of it and hopefully when you have time in the evening may be you could help it with some more info, would be really useful for guys like me who would search this post in future

Comment: Well if you need a skeleton, check on the other validators as already written. They are all pretty the same but differ in the way what options they take and what they're validating (obviously). Just copy one, put it into your dir, rename it, implement the isValid method and that's pretty it. I'll give you an example this evening.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, will try to take one of the validators already written, will play with it and will also be keeping my fingers crossed for your example(take your time) :). Some how basing on your example if my module works I will definitely accept your answer

Answer (score 5):

if you use the DoctrineModule, there is already a [validator for your case](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/tree/master/src/DoctrineModule/Validator).

Comment: Hi thanks for your info, can you please give a brief info how to use these modules with a small example which in my case is the Album Module from Rob Allen and Jason Grimes

Comment: i dont know about the Album Module from Rob. The NoObjectExist Validator is just a Validator like others. (it extends Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator). So you need to create an InputFilter to your from and attach these validators. I played a little around this in my repo [link]https://github.com/dawinterfeldt/playground/blob/master/module/User/src/User/Service/RegisterFormFactory.php mybe it gives you a hint.