# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2 Error message

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have been trying to add more flexibilities to the Album Module from Zend Framework 2. In that process I have been trying to set a validator for one of the form fields especially for the album name which in my case the column name in my database is title.

I have been following the validation part from one of the previous answers to my post, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300472/validation-in-zend-framework-2-with-doctrine-2/12315350#comment16543609_12315350)

I have been using that class in my albumcontroller class in this fashion:

```
<?php

namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Album\Entity\Album\Album;
use Album\Form\AlbumForm;
use Album\Model\Album\AlbumExists;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class AlbumController
extends AbstractActionController
{
 public function addAction()
     {
        $form = new AlbumForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Add');

        $query = "SELECT a.title FROM Album\Entity\Album\Album a";
        $albumExists = new AlbumExists($this->getEntityManager(), $query, 'title');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost())
        {
            $album = new Album();
            $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            $title = $this->getRequest()->getPost('title');

            if ($form->isValid() && $albumExists->isValid($title))
            {
                 $album->populate($form->getData());
                 $this->getEntityManager()->persist($album);
                 $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
            }
        }
        return array('form' => $form);
    }
```

When I enter a album name/title which is already in the database it throws an error in this fashion:

> ```
> An error occurred during execution; please try again later.  
> Additional information:
> Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException  
>
> File:
> C:\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException.php:69
>
> Message:
> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.
> ```

Any idea where Im making a mistake?

Comment: Don't be afraid to cast votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're using "my" class and haven't modified that part, you're missing the WHERE condition in your query.

In the class, a parameter `:value` is bound, so you have to use this parameter in your query (e.g. `WHERE a.title = :value`).

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for pointing it out, but I am having a small problem. It is checking the existing title, when found it just stays displays the form with filled in data, how can show the error message "There is already an entity with this value."

Comment: Add the validator directly in the form's inputfilter / validator definitions or assign it to the form in the controller

Comment: You can do the latter by `$form->getInputFilter()->get('title')->getValidatorChain()->add($validator);`. The validator will then be taken into account when you call $form->isValid().

Comment: Well I edited my comment but you can also find tons of information in the docs I've given you in your last question -> http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#zend-form These are the docs which I've used to learn it.

Comment: any idea why Im getting this fatal error message `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain::add() in C:\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php`, when I tried to assign the validator to the form in my AlbumController like this `$form->getInputFilter()->get('title')->getValidatorChain()->add($albumExists);`

Comment: Yes, sorry, its `addValidator()`, not `add()`. See also the `Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain` class.