# Assign a validator to the form in controller using Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

I have a question about the Zend Framework 2, can some one provide an example code or link of how I can attach a validator class to the form in my controller so that it displays the error messages from the validator. A Zend framework developer has suggested me to use this

```
$form->getInputFilter()->get('entityName')->getValidatorChain()->add($validator);
```

when I added this line in my controller, throws me this error when I try to add a new entity

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain::add() in C:\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php
```

In case if somebody familiar with Zend Framework can help me to sort out this. I am purely searching for ways to add the validator to my form in controller. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. My AlbumController code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368939/zend-framework-2-doctrine-2-error-message/12369236#12369236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, it's actually `addValidator($validator)`, not just `add($validator)`.

But you could have seen this if you had a look at the sources.

Also, I don't think it was necessary to create a new question for this. I would have answered this also in your latest question.

// Edit: oops, just saw that you asked in your latest question, sorry for this.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I was waiting for a response from you in the previous post, but I thought it would grab your attention here :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer to this that doesn't require any reference documentation is to understand what the error message is telling you. In this case the `add()` method doesn't exist in the ValidatorChain class. So, open up that class in your editor. If you use one with good code-introspection you can go into any public method and type `$this->` and hit the autocomplete shortcut (usually ctrl + spacebar). This should give you a catelog of methods available to you. Scan through the methods that start with a sensible name for what you're trying to do like add* and you'll stumble upon the answer: `addValidator()`

I wanted to leave this as a comment but I started to ramble a bit.

Comment: Hi Mike, please dont be too harsh on me as Im getting used to these things. Anyway thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @webMot I didn't intend to come off as harsh. I use this method very frequently when dealing with any code base that has a lot of OOP (read: zF). Leveraging your IDE in the ways I outlined above will help you immensely in your travels. Another example is if you want to add a validator to a form element but you're not exactly sure which filter to use. Using your editor you can simply type `new Zend_Filter<Ctrl+Space>` and you'll have a list of all zend filters.

Comment: thanks for pointing that as well, good suggestions for starters like me

Comment: (Note: In ZF2, classes are separated in namespaces, so you need to enter \Zend\Filter\<Ctrl Space> to see the available sub-namespaces and classes)