# How to persist only one end of a relationship and the other one only if the entity doesn't exist?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, one-to-many, many-to-one, persist

I have a complex/nested object created by automatic hydration from `Zend\Form` data. Now I want to save it with Doctrine 2. The best case would be just one `persist(...)` and one `flush(...)` call on the top level. But it doesn't work like this. So now I have following problem:

There are objects `User` and `Order`. The relationship is `1:n` (so, `1` `User` has `n` `Order`s). The `User` exists already. When a `User` `Joe` tries to save more than one `Order` (e.g. its second order), an error occurs:

> A new entity was found through the relationship '...\Order#user' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: ...\User@000000003ba4559d000000005be8d831. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement '...\User#__toString()' to get a clue.

Allright, I add `cascade={"persist"}` (though it doesn't make sense here, but anyway, just to try it out):

```
class Order
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $user;
    ...
}
```

Now it works, if the given `User` doesn't exist: An `Order` and a `User` is created.

But if the `User` exists, an error occurs:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (username, role, created, updated) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["myusername", "member", null, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'myusername' for key 'username_UNIQUE'

**How to handle the saving so, that the `User` only gets saved, if it doesn't exist yet?**

Comment: are you validating this object with symfony form (or only the validation component)? take a look at the [UniqueEntity Constraints](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I'm using the `Zend\Form`, not Symfony. For the form validating I use the Zend validation functionnality.

Comment: Almost every time I run into the Doctrine error "A new entity was found through the relationship '...\Order#user' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity" I find that I have done something wrong, usually something small. 

In English that error is telling you that the order was persisted, but the user associated with it has not been persisted. This means the user being assigned is not known to Doctrine as an Entity that is in the database. Check your code carefully, verify you are actually assigning a the proper User and that it is a valid user.

Comment: check if this anwer is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/17000801/2270041

Comment: @MEmerson Thank you for the hint! But I have now the error `1062 Duplicate entry` -- exactly because Doctrine tries to save (`INSERT`) the existing `User` again. So, how can it be avoided?

Comment: @Matteo Thanks, but it's not about input filtering. It's a Doctrine issue. Just opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6781).

Comment: @automatix that means that somehow you are creating a new entity and populating it with the same information, then trying to save it. You need to actually put the original entity object into the Order, not populating a new entity with the same info and persisting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to persist the `User` before saving the referencing entity. If it doesn't exist yet, it needs to be created (`persist`ed and `flush`ed) first:

```
$user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(
    ['username' => $dataObject->getUser()->getUsername()]
);
if (! $user) {
    $this->entityManager->persist($dataObject->getUser());
    $this->entityManager->flush($dataObject->getUser());
    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(
        ['username' => $dataObject->getUser()->getUsername()]
    );
}
$dataObject->setUser($user);

$this->entityManager->persist($dataObject);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

And the `cascade={"persist"}` should not be used, since it actually doesn't make sense in this case.

---

**EDIT**

Or even easier:

```
$user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(
    ['username' => $dataObject->getUser()->getUsername()]
);
if ($user) {
    $dataObject->setUser($user);
} else {
    $this->entityManager->persist($dataObject->getUser());
}

$this->entityManager->persist($dataObject);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```